# Heatmap of line segments in 3-D space projected onto 2-D plane

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a set of data containing the start and endpoints of line segments which exist in 3-D space. Along with the spatial data, I also have an associated value of the volume of the physical element the line segments represent. The volumes are independent of those of other segments (i.e., two segments with the same length do not necessarily have the same volume). Typically, most segments are parallel to an axis, although this is certainly not always the case. I have about 5,000 elements in this dataset:

[image: Description of data]

Due to the fact that I have so many overlapping segments, my goal is to project each element onto the xy, xz, and yz planes and plot a heatmap of the volumetric intensity of the planar projection. For example, see the sketch of a set of monkey bars and the xy and xz heatmaps below. In the 3-D plot, linewidths have been weighted to show volumes.

[image: sketch of sample data]

My data is currently stored in a Pandas DataFrame and I am plotting in Matplotlib. Since I have the coordinates of all elements, coordinate projection is no issue. However, I am not sure how to increase the intensities of the heatmap when elements intersect or are projected with a shorter length. I will also need to expand this dataset to include two-dimensional shapes and three-dimensional forms also defined by a set of two points and a volume parameter. Any ideas are appreciated.